# Asp.Net MVC Validations Not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
[Display(Name = "SentDoc_lblDescription ", ResourceType = typeof(EXTDocuments.Resources))]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Description Required")]
public string Description {get;set;}
```

This `Description` Property is required in business logic.

When I am clicking submit button it throws an error.

The error is decription is null, I want to validate that property from within the UI.

Comment: Mind to post some of your code? It is very difficult to help you without knowing what you have tried.

Comment: You need to post your view code, and your controller code... as well as the ACTUAL error message you are getting (including any types and call stacks).  Reinterpreting the error means that you can only tell us your understanding of the problem, which may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I want to recall running into something like this and currently use this attribute set in order to ensure my strings get validated correctly:

```
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
```

By using the MinLength and Required, you get a required string with a minimum length. Hopefully this helps you out.